# How to filter list of Birthday in Pandas-Python

Tags: python, pandas, date

Based on the example table, I would like to select today's birthday records using Pandas in Python. I've already tried to build a filter using "dataframe.loc", but I couldn't build a mask that works. If today's date is "01/01", then the names "AAA" and "BBB" should be selected.

How to create a filter or mask to select records of birthday?

```
NAME     BIRTHDAY
AAA      1980-01-01
BBB      1985-01-01
CCC      1981-03-15
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One approach would be to use [`strftime`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.strftime.html) to compare just the month and day:

```
# Convert to DateTime if not already
df['BIRTHDAY'] = pd.to_datetime(df['BIRTHDAY'])
# Set Day for Comparison
today = pd.to_datetime('2021-01-01').strftime('%m-%d')
# Filter DataFrame
today_df = df.loc[df['BIRTHDAY'].dt.strftime('%m-%d').eq(today)]
```

`today_df`:

```
  NAME   BIRTHDAY
0  AAA 1980-01-01
1  BBB 1985-01-01
```

---

With an added entry for today 07/04 and using `pd.Timestamp.now()` to get the current DateTime:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'NAME': {0: 'AAA', 1: 'BBB', 2: 'CCC', 3: 'DDD'},
                   'BIRTHDAY': {0: '1980-01-01', 1: '1985-01-01',
                                2: '1981-03-15', 3: '1983-07-04'}})

# Convert to DateTime if not already
df['BIRTHDAY'] = pd.to_datetime(df['BIRTHDAY'])
# Set Day for Comparison Using Today's DateTime
today = pd.Timestamp.now().strftime('%m-%d')
# Filter DataFrame
today_df = df.loc[df['BIRTHDAY'].dt.strftime('%m-%d').eq(today)]
```

`today_df`:

```
  NAME   BIRTHDAY
3  DDD 1983-07-04
```

Comment: i'd vote to keep `today` as a Timestamp and do `df[(df["BIRTHDAY"].month == today.month) & (df["BIRTHDAY"].day == today.day)]` just because it feels better to me to skip the stringing, but same idea. more importantly, WHAT ARE WE GONNA DO FOR THE FEB 29TH BIRTHDAY PEOPLE?????

Comment: Thanks Henry Ecker. It works fine! @mway, maybe i can do an "or" comparision for FEB 29TH BIRTHDAY. Isn't it?